# Can you use the Ionic framework to build Mac apps?

Tags: angularjs, macos, ionic-framework

The title pretty much says it all. I was asked this question today and really didn't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is not intended to build desktop, or even desktop browser based applications.

Comment: I know its made for mobile, but what I'm wondering if its possible.

Comment: I don't think there is a suitable desktop compatible web container like cordova etc.  Many things are *possible* but it would probably be a very impractical use of your time.

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs :

> Ionic is focused on building native/hybrid mobile apps rather than
>   mobile websites.
>
> As such, our browser support tends to be whatever Web View API is
>   available to native apps on a given platform. For Ionic 1.0.0
>   "uranium-unicorn", that means UIWebView for iOS 7+, and Android 4.1
>   and up. Windows Phone and FirefoxOS support is on our roadmap.

Even if you implement a browser website using ionic, the rendered output would rather weird.

Infact, Ionic has itself implemented it's website using bootstrap ;)

[image]